# What percentage of board games on the market involve dice?

Tags: game-design

I realise there is probably no way to get an accurate figure, just looking for a ballpark estimate of approximately how many board games there are out there, and how many of those involve dice rolling.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/#) has 58627 games listed*, and 11132 of them are marked with the [dice-rolling mechanic](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2072/dice-rolling)** . So that's 19% - but of course, there's no guarantee that all of the games were appropriately tagged, so treat it as a lower bound.

If you're curious about more specific categories, you can used the [advanced search](http://boardgamegeek.com/advsearch/boardgame) and limit it to games with or without dice rolling with some other restrictions. But it maxes out at 1000 results (ten pages), and doesn't count them for you.

<sub>* Hover over "browse" on the home page 

** 1114 pages of "linked items", 10 per page, 2 on the last page.</sub>

Comment: A good answer to a less-good question. +1